# Падает сквозь Terrain

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игрок, он должен проходить через объект (капсулу).Проблема в том что когда я на этот объект(капсулу) устанавливаю <kbd>isTrigger ✅</kbd> то он проваливается сквозь Terrain что нужно сделать чтобы он не падал и при этом игрок мог пройти сквозь его?

Comment: ну так поставь ему один коллайдер и один триггер.к тому же есть CharacterController, если от него ведется управление, который выполняет роль коллайдера

Comment: У него capsule collider

Comment: ..............И?

Comment: Не понял, я могу прислать скриншот unity

Comment: _"ну так поставь ему один коллайдер и один триггер"_ не понял что надо сделать

Comment: на объект можно ставить хоть миллион коллайдеров и триггеров. поставь один коллайдер и один триггер

Comment: у него стоит 1 триггер и 1 коллайдер но капсула все-равно падает сквозь terrain

Comment: `у него стоит 1 триггер и 1 коллайдер но капсула все-равно падает сквозь terrain` - враньё! .................. прикольно - вопрос поменялся..... Вообще не ясна суть, что за капсула и какую роль она играет. Если она тупо "стоит", то 1) на ней можно не ставить не коллайдеры ни `rigidBody` и тупо поставить на нужное место 2) а можно сделать вообще потомком терейна.

Comment: Извини, забыл. У него включен gravity

Comment: ну так смысл не изменился. какую функцию она (капсула) выполняет? почему не отключить у нее ненужные компоненты просто?

Comment: Physics.IgnoreCollision или слой в physics настройках чтобы не колизился с нужным слоем

Answer (score 0):

Триггер - это поле, при попадании на которое что то происходит. Соответственно RigidBody нет смысла вешать )

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос